# Deploy to IBM Cloud Kubernetes from deployment.yml

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud

I have developed my microservice ecosystem and i managed to deploy and run it localy using docker containers and minikube. For each service i have specified two files: deployment.yml (pod specification) and service.yml (service specification). When I deploy each service to minikube cluster i simply run:

> kubectl create -f deployment.yml

and after that

> kubectl create -f service.yml

Now I want to deploy microservice ecosystem to IBM Cloud Services. I spend some time researching the deployment procedures and I did not find any using the deployment.yml and service.yml when deploying services.

My question is, can I just somehow deploy my services using existing deployment.yml and service.yml files?

Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was confused about the deployment steps.

I just needed to go to IBM Cloud Service dashboard, find my cluster, click on cluster link and follow the steps in the Access section on the page.

After finishing the steps described within the section we can deploy our services as we were using the minikube and kubectl locally.

Answer (score 1):

As long as it's kubernetes under the hood and kubernetes API is accessible (kubectl works) you can do exactly the same. Is it sustainable in long term, that depends on your case, but likely it is not and I would suggest looking into stuff like ie. Helm